# Virtual Dirs in ASP.Net Project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, relative-path, virtual-directory

My team are working in a corporate environment, building multiple ASP.Net apps (v3.5 in VS2008 and VB.Net - no flames please!) to a standard look & feel.

Rather than copy the same images, stylesheets, etc. into every new project and have to maintain the lot, I'd prefer to make use of something like a virtual directory WITHIN each project that refers to a single source (probably a URL on an external IIS box)

Is there anything I can do WITHIN the project / project template to provide this without having to configure Virtual Directories on developer PCs and each and every application on the dev, test and production IIS boxes? I'd also rather not have to provide a fully-qualified URL to the production box for every image and stylesheet.

For example, rather than having to write:

```
<img src="http://ProductionServer/CorpStandards/logo.png" />
```

I'd prefer the devs to be able to do the following:

```
<img src="CorpStandards/logo.png" />
```

where **CorpStandards** is a virtual directory within the project rather than a physical folder containing a copy of all the files.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can have what you wish but not without having to setup a new virtual directory in Each Website.

Here's what you need to do (way i prefer), Open  IIS manager.

Then in `Connections` under `Sites` Select The Website and RightClick on it, Select
 `Add Virtual Directory...` from the Context menu. in The dialogue box that opens Enter the Alias name of your choice like `"GlobalImages"` and Browse the physical path of the Folder you want to want Select it and Click OK. You will have it available for relative url in that website.

You need to repeat the same step for each website.

Good luck..

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: That'll help me setup Virtual Dirs under IIS, but is there any way to add them into the project (like a regular folder) ?

Comment: When you set that in IIS, it is automatically added to your Solution's Project. I don't think There is an option for doing this in Visual Studio, and wwwroot/<projectname> folder doesn't allow creating shortcut link to other folders. Even if you are making a WebApplication Project still you may create shortcut links in your project folder but they are not mapped to virtual folders.